# Clustering in windows azure

Tags: azure, cloud, load-balancing, hyper-v, hypervisor

Is clustering possible in windows azure? can we transfer azure vms to hyper v or any other hypervisors and vice varsa?if any one have idea regarding this please let me know.

Comment: Please tag more carefully. You tagged this as [tag:cluster-analysis], but you probably meant [tag:load-balancing].

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the [IaaS feature - Virtual Machines](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/virtual-machines/). Also it is possible to transfer your VM from Windows Azure Virtual Machines to local Hyper-V, or any other hypervisor that supports the VHD format. But, of course you have to manage the OS level feature entirely by yourself!

You can check [this teched video](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/06/15/what-s-supported-inside-a-windows-azure-virtual-machine-windowsazure-msteched-itcamp.aspx) by Mark Russinovich for more info.